# Adobe Flex: Injecting data and mediating events in modules with Swiz

Tags: apache-flex, module, event-handling, inject, swiz

Since my application is getting bigger, I decided to fragment my project into several modules, but the documentation from Swiz on Modules is very poor (http://swizframework.jira.com/wiki/display/SWIZ/Module+Support). I tried out the Swiz Examples (http://www.briankotek.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/8/16/Swiz-Example-Application-Demonstrating-Module-Support) but I couldn't inject any data into my module or even catch an event. The module is loaded properly however.

Ideally I will end up having multiple Flex-Projects, each containing one module and each .swf file is deployed into the application deploy folder.

However if you aren't famililiar with a structure like that, but instead you know how to inject data/event mediating into a module inside the same Flex project, I'd also be happy to read your advice/knowledge.

Any helpful answers welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Swiz, but I have had great results using [SwiftSuspenders](https://github.com/tschneidereit/SwiftSuspenders) - you can have very complex modular structures completely decoupled and loaded separately.

What might be an issue you want to check first, though, is which [ApplicationDomain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSd75bf4610ec9e22f43855da312214da1d8f-8000.html) you load your module into: If you are going to use a common class loader, inject data and catch events properly, it should be loaded into `currentDomain`.

In any case - SwiftSuspenders is worth looking at...